# PostgreSQL more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

Running `PostgreSQL 9.6`.
I'm trying to output rows consisting of a value and a list of names.
This is my query:

```
SELECT name, (SELECT car_name FROM cars WHERE user = id)
FROM users WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY name;
```

But it fails with:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

It of course make sense, but I would like to have the nested query to be outputted as a list or `json`.
I've tried with `row_to_json`, but that fails also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an aggregation function, such as `string_agg()` or `json_agg()`:

```
SELECT name,
       (SELECT string_agg(car_name) FROM cars WHERE user = id)
FROM users
WHERE user_id = 1
ORDER BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the `JOIN` instead :

```
SELECT u.name, string_agg(c.car_name)
FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     cars c
     ON c.id = u.user
WHERE u.user_id = 1
GROUP BY u.name
ORDER BY u.name;
```

Comment: Seems to work, but returns ex. `["car_nameX", "car_nameY"]. Can it return `[{ "car_name": "car_nameX"}, {...}]